# IntelliJ IDEA - можно ли автоматически увеличивать номер сборки (версии)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Есть Java-Gradle проект. При выполнении задачи build собирается jar файл проекта с именем artifact-1.0.jar. Нужно чтобы при каждом выполнении задачи build версия изменялась. Пример:

- artifact-1.0-1.jar.
- artifact-1.0-5.jar.
- artifact-1.0-20.jar.
- ...
- artifact-1.0-N.jar.

Как правильно реализовать это?

Comment: Для этого, как вариант, есть плагин nebula.release от netflix, можно настроить различное представление имени версии  в зависимости от того, что именно собирается (девелоперская сборка, девелоперский снапшот, релиз-кандидат, релиз), все это интегрировано с гитом.. Можно, конечно и по своему костылить как в примерах ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нам нужно написать файл ant xml. Этот файл будет создавать файл, где номер сборки будет сохранен и увеличен, а затем он просмотрит файл исходного кода `${src}/com/yourPath/Main.java` для переменной `public static final String BUILD_NUMBER = ".*";` и замените ее на текущий номер сборки.

Файл xml будет выглядеть так:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="init" basedir=".">
    <description>
        simple example increment build variable
    </description>
  <!-- set global properties for this build -->
  <property name="src" location="../src"/>

  <target name="init">
    <echo file="myAntOut.txt">My first ant ${src} ${line.separator}</echo>

    <buildnumber/>
    <replaceregexp file="${src}/com/yourPath/Main.java"
               match="public\s+static\s+final\s+String\s+BUILD_NUMBER\s+=\s+&quot;.*&quot;;"
               replace="public static final String BUILD_NUMBER = &quot;${build.number}&quot;;"
               byline="true"
    />

  </target>
</project>
```

Затем в вашем IntelliJ вы нажимаете `View->Tool Windows->Ant Build`. Затем `+` и перейдите к вашему xml файлу (обратите внимание, что текущий путь, используемый вашим xml, станет путем для самого файла xml, а не для проекта inteliJ, поэтому вы можете исправить часть `location="../src"` в зависимости от того, где вы храните свой XML). Затем вы увидите нашу цель `init`, которую вы можете выбрать, и нажмите кнопку `play`. Если он работает, вы увидите `BUILD_NUMBER`, добавленный в исходный код `Main.java`. Теперь важный трюк, как сделать это автоматически: просто щелкните правой кнопкой мыши по `init` и выберите `Execute on->Before Compilation`. Всё, больше ничего, готово :)

Вот [оригинал](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265750/intellij-idea-can-i-have-automatically-incremented-build-version-number)

Answer (score 3):

Если все происходит под `git` + `gradle` (а сейчас это почти всегда так) - то я делаю это примерно так:

1) В `build.gradle` определяем функцию, которая считает номер сборки (начиная от корня):

```
def getBuildCode = { ->
    try {
        def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        exec {
            standardOutput = stdout
            commandLine 'git', 'rev-list', '--first-parent', '--count', 'master'
        }
        println("Build #"+stdout)
        return asInteger(stdout.toString("ASCII").trim())
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

2) Далее в генерацию jar вставляем номер сборки:

```
def buildCode=getBuildCode()

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    baseName = project.name + '-' + buildCode
    from { ... }
    with jar
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще добавлять именно порядковый номер не лучшая идея. Т.к. при очистке сборочных данных этот номер потеряется. Да и сканирование предыдущих версий не самая простая задача. Лучше добавлять метку времени. В простейшем случае для **Groovy DSL** это делается так:

```
String versionSuffix = "-"+System.currentTimeMillis()
jar {
    archiveVersion.set(project.version.toString() + versionSuffix)
}
```

Для **Kotlin DSL** так:

```
val versionSuffix: String = "-"+System.currentTimeMillis()
tasks.named<Jar>("jar") {
    archiveVersion.set(project.version.toString() + versionSuffix)
}
```